# golang bazel docker error: could not launch process: fork/exec /go/src/my_bin_svc: function not implemented

Tags: docker, go, bazel, delve, dlv

I am trying to setup a Delve (dlv) debugger for a GO binary that was built with Bazel.

The binary is to be run within Docker. It runs fine on its own.

But when i try to setup Delve ( dlv ) i get the following error:

`could not launch process: fork/exec /go/src/my_bin_svc: function not implemented`

Here is the description of the system and build tools:

Host system: Mac OS M1

Build tools: Bazel, building for linux-amd64

Runtime: Docker ( Docker version 20.10.17 )

Here is my bazel build command:

`bazelisk build -c dbg --platforms=@io_bazel_rules_go//go/toolchain:linux_amd64 //...`

Here is my BUILD file for my specific service that i am targetting:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")


go_library(
    name = "cmd_lib",
    srcs = ["main.go"],
    importpath = "github.com/xxxxxxxxxx/src/go-grpc-order-svc/cmd",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    deps = [
        "//pkg/event",
        "//pkg/schema",
        "//proto/order",
        "//src/go-grpc-order-svc/pkg/client",
        "//src/go-grpc-order-svc/pkg/config",
        "//src/go-grpc-order-svc/pkg/db",
        "//src/go-grpc-order-svc/pkg/repository",
        "//src/go-grpc-order-svc/pkg/service",
        "@com_github_tinrab_retry//:retry",
        "@org_golang_google_grpc//:go_default_library",
    ],
)

go_binary(
    name = "cmd",
    embed = [":cmd_lib"],
    goarch = "amd64",
    goos = "linux",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.18-bullseye

ENV GOOS="linux"
ENV APP_HOME /go/src
RUN mkdir -p "$APP_HOME"

WORKDIR "$APP_HOME"


EXPOSE 50053
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 4000

RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64  CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -gcflags="all=-N -l" -ldflags "-s -w -extldflags '-static'" github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

ENV GO111MODULE=off

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/linux_amd64/dlv", "--listen=:4000", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--log=true", "exec", "/go/src/my_bin_svc"]
```

Here is the part of docker-compose to start my service:

```
    my-bin-svc:
        build:
          dockerfile: src/go-grpc-order-svc/Dockerfile.debug
          context: .        
        volumes:
            #- ./bazel-bin/src/go-grpc-order-svc/cmd/cmd_/cmd:/go/src/order_svc
            - ./bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg/bin/src/go-grpc-order-svc/cmd/cmd_/cmd:/go/src/my_bin_svc
        ports:
            - "50053:50053"        
        networks:
            - backend          
        links:
            - order-db
        depends_on:
            - order-db
```

Now in bazel i have several folders that contain binaries:

**bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg** <--- which if i am not mistaken contains binaries with debugging symbols ( what i need to use with delve ? ). Binaries from here run fine on their own ( without delve ), but give the above error when are given to dlv.

I also have

**bazel-bin** <--- which contains my linux binaries that run fine on their own, but give the above error when are given to dlv.

I have tried to search for that specific error but so far did not see anything concrete.

Has anyone seen that error and has any idea what this is ?

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use platform specific targets in docker-compose:

platform: linux/amd64

But so far without success.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with debugging in an amd64 container on ARM, and as far as I can see the only workarounds are to either use QEMU emulation or linux/arm64-based images. See also [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5191) and the original [report on the dlv repo](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2910). The first link contains some more details on getting it to work

Comment: Thank you, using linux/arm64-based seems to have solved my issue.